# BeautifulSoup how to index tag object

Tags: python, object, indexing, beautifulsoup, tags

I have this html code:

```
<tr class="even">
  <td style="background: #8FB9B0; color: #8FB9B0;">0&#160;</td>
  <td>Plupp</td>
  <td class="right">RIFLEMAN</td>
  <td class="right">139</td>
  <td class="right">6</td>
  <td class="right">30</td>
  <td class="right" title="Packet loss: ">64</td>
  <td class="center">No</td>
  <td class="center">No</td>
  <td class="center">Yes</td>
```

which is the second tr with class 'even'. I want to extract from here the second td aka Plupp, and the 3rd aka RIFLEMAN

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong, here is my code:

```
tr = soup.find_all('tr', class_='even')[1]
a = tr[2].find('td')
```

I get this error:

```
  File "test.py", line 45, in <module>
    a = tr[2].find('td')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem starts with:

```
tr = soup.find_all('tr', class_='even')[1]
```

it is the `[1]` at the end of the line that means the thing returned is a single tag not a list of tags, but in your next line:

```
a = tr[2].find('td')
```

you attempt to index an object with no index, may I suggest the way to achieve your goal is to replace this line with :

```
tds = tr.find_all("td") # returns a list of td's within the tr
a = tds[2] # accesses RIFLEMAN
b = tds[1] # accesses Pupp.
```

Comment: Makes sense ! Thank you for taking the time to explain, Paula, code works and I understood !

Answer (score 1):

The first line is returning an array with all tr tags with class attribute "even".  The [1] array index selector says to select the second tr tag in the array (remember arrays start at 0).

At this point the tr object is not an array or any kind of collection you would use brackets on, it is a beautiful soup tag object.   The error is saying that [2] is not a valid operation to perform on the tr object.